# can multiple tcp sockets be marked as kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP in a VOIP App?

Tags: cocoa-touch, sockets, ios5, voip

I'm having some confusion if a VOIP App can have multiple tcp sockets monitored in background via kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP option. Apple documentation says mark one of the sockets but doesn't say that multiple sockets can't be used.

My sample code with 2 tcp sockets seems to be working fine in background but wanted to confirm that it is not just some fluke and actually supported by iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work, you can mark any (and as many) VOIP TCP sockets as you like. The 'use case' here would be if you have a VOIP client registering against multiple servers, each of those sockets would require a separate TCP socket, and thus have the VOIP property assigned.

I think the docs are actually referencing that you only need to set ONE socket per service you're registered against (as opposed to one per app).